# How to show two columns in woocommerce product categories?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce product categories, and I want to display product categories in two columns, instead of 1 column. I tried to change the CSS code to

```
@media (max-width: 479px) {
.et_pb_column .woocommerce ul.products li.product:nth-child(n), .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product:nth-child(n), .et_gallery_item:nth-child(n) {
width: 48% !important;
}
}
@media only screen and ( max-width: 480px ) {
.woocommerce-page .woocommerce ul.products li.product:nth-child(n) {
margin-right: 5px !important;
margin-top: 5px !important;
margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}
}
@media (max-width: 479px){
.et_pb_row_fullwidth.custom-fullwidth-row {
width: 100% !important;
max-width: 100% !important;
margin: 0;
}
.custom-fullwidth-row .woocommerce {
padding: 0 5px 0 5px !important;
}}
```

However, it does not show the two columns product categories. How can I fix it? This is my full CSS code

```
body.boxed .main-menu-wrap { background: #0088cc; padding: 8px 0; }
.home-slider.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev,
.home-slider.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next{
    background: transparent;
    color: #544e4e;
    font-size: 40px;   
}
.home-slider.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev{
    left: 20px;
}
.home-slider.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next{
    right: 20px;
}
.home-slider.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev:before{
    content: '\e84f';
}
.home-slider.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next:before{
    content: '\e850';
}
i.widget-title-icon {
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #2f2727;
}
#main.main-boxed .vc_row.custom-line-full{
    max-width: inherit;
    left: -1000px !important;
    width: 3000px !important;
}
@media (max-width: 479px) {
.et_pb_column .woocommerce ul.products li.product:nth-child(n), .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product:nth-child(n), .et_gallery_item:nth-child(n) {
width: 48% !important;
}
}
@media only screen and ( max-width: 480px ) {
.woocommerce-page .woocommerce ul.products li.product:nth-child(n) {
margin-right: 5px !important;
margin-top: 5px !important;
margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}
}
@media (max-width: 479px){
.et_pb_row_fullwidth.custom-fullwidth-row {
width: 100% !important;
max-width: 100% !important;
margin: 0;
}
.custom-fullwidth-row .woocommerce {
padding: 0 5px 0 5px !important;
}}
```

Update: 
Just change the CSS file as

```
@media (max-width:479px){ 
    ul.pcols-ls-1 li.product, .column2 ul.pcols-ls-1 li.product, ul.pcols-ls-1 li.product-category, .column2 ul.pcols-ls-1 li.product-category { 
        width: 50% !important; } }
```

Comment: provide website link

Comment: so you want to show category page in two column on mobile width?

Comment: Right. It is just one column now. You can check it

Comment: not it's showing already with two column check this http://prntscr.com/fxx3je  if I am wrong to provided exact URL of the page cause your website is in different language

Comment: Sorry, it is product detail. You must go to home page and see it. I will translate it to english now. Can you check it again .

Comment: Sorry this your home page also look like this http://prntscr.com/fxx4o9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149669/discussion-between-user8264-and-raj-kumar-bhardwaj).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#owlCarousel").owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:2,
            nav:true
        },
        600:{
            items:3,
            nav:false
        },
        1000:{
            items:5,
            nav:true,
            loop:false
        }
    }
})
```

Now go to your custom js script sections of the theme if is it into your theme.
then paste above javascript code. also, you need to check your slider id if it is different than use your slider id instead of this  #owlCarousel in above code

Comment: Your way is so complex and may not work. I just ask about changing CSS. I found other solution and it worked well. Let check in the update question

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below link.

```
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-number-of-products-per-row/
```

It will chow you how to manage the rows and product limit in the woo commerce.

Comment: Sorry. My target is mobile. It must be change in CSS file. In desktop, it worked well

Comment: ok . then you need to make some chnages in css file. using media queries

Comment: So, that is my question. Could you read my question more detail